# PARSE JSON action not returning string from JSON in Logic Apps

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I am sending below JSON to a service bus and then parsing using Parse JSON in the Logic App. But InvoiceLineItems is coming as null. Any thoughts?

```
{
  "BaselineDate": "2021-02-18",
  "ContactName": null,
  "DueDate": "2021-02-18",
  "DocumentType": "DG",
  "InvoiceLineItems": "[{\"itemLineNumber\":\"001\",\"itemCode\":null,\"itemDetails\":\"Test normal payment for Invoice\",\"unitPrice\":\"10\",\"orderQuantity\":null,\"gstInclAmount\":\"10\",\"glAccount\":\"1120001100\",\"costCentre\":null,\"taxCode\":\"S5\",\"accountType\":\"D\",\"clearingDocument\":\"1600001193\",\"comment1\":null,\"comment2\":null,\"comment3\":null,\"clearingDate\":\"2021-02-18\"},{\"itemLineNumber\":\"002\",\"itemCode\":null,\"itemDetails\":null,\"unitPrice\":\"10\",\"orderQuantity\":null,\"gstInclAmount\":\"10\",\"glAccount\":\"4100006100\",\"costCentre\":\"8606\",\"taxCode\":\"S5\",\"accountType\":\"S\",\"clearingDocument\":null,\"comment1\":null,\"comment2\":null,\"comment3\":null,\"clearingDate\":null}]"
}
```

The schema to parse is below:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "BaselineDate": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ContactName": {},
    "DocumentType": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "DueDate": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "InvoiceLineItems": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details  such as screenshots of how did you deal with the json in logic app and how did you process it to service bus ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you parsing the input data? I just tested and it works fine.

Schema:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "BaselineDate": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "ContactName": {},
        "DocumentType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "DueDate": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "InvoiceLineItems": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

Output:
[image]